# Remote Connecting to Windows

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote

Is it possible to connect to a Windows Server machine command line without using RDP, in similar manner to SSHing to a Linux server?  My tasks require running various commands in many Windows machines.

Should I just use Cygwin with OpenSSH Server and Screen?  How stable is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remote manage and script Windows machines you should look into [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa973757%28v=vs.85%29) and [Powershell Remoting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/remoting-with-powershell-quickstart/)

Answer (score 2):

Of course.  You already know the answer.  [OpenSSh](http://www.openssh.com/) will do it.  There is a Windows compiled version called [CopSSH](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) that we've used successfully in production for years.

Comment: Windows also supports Telnet by default... but that isn't secure.  Hopefully some day MS will get on the SSH boat.

Comment: Depending on the version of Windows, telnet is available but not installed by default.

Comment: Not installed, but supported.  Install it by clicking on Windows Components in `Add/Remove Programs`.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a product called Windows Remote Management.  Here's one of the utilities:

`Winrs.exe`

This command line tool enables administrators to remotely execute most Cmd.exe commands using the WS-Management protocol.

Read more at:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your environment and requirements, you might look at pstools from Microsoft. It will allow you to run commands or scripts across several machines.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649

I'm sure that PowerShell is a bit more elegant, but this set of tools is handy, especially if you have some vb scripts that that you haven't converted to PowerShell yet.

Answer (score 0):

[WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) is an excellent SSH Server implementation for Windows.  It's free for non-commercial use, and reasonably priced ($100 / Server) for commercal use.